# ¿Cómo obtener el mensaje de error de una petición REST con CURL PHP?

Tags: php, html

¿Cómo obtengo el mensaje de error de una respuesta HTML?

Por ejemplo, un web service me retorna un error 401 y en el header le pongo un mensaje. Actualmente obtengo el número del error con el header:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)
```

Me retorna 401 pero no puedo conseguir tomar el valor del mensaje de error. He probado con:

```
curl_error();
curl_strerror();
```

Y no he podido obtener el `Unauthorized`.

Comment: Al parecer no es posible. Esta [contribución del manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-getinfo.php#41332) muestra una forma de hacerlo, colocando los códigos de error en un archivo  `ini` y obteniendo los mensajes de error según el código de error obtenido. La nota data de 13 años quizá ¿? cURL haya evolucionado después en ese sentido. Si no, queda hacerlo a mano, con esa opción o con un `switch ... case... `

Comment: Creo que sería más fácil si usaras alguna librería como `Guzzle` para ello.

Comment: Revise la documentacion de la libreria y por lo que pude observar no es de un manejo muy complejo gracias por la ayuda.